# symbolic link issue in windows

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

I'trying to make a symbolic link for dropbox folder which will refer to music directory, so the command I entered was the following: mklink \D d:\User\Dropbox d:\User\My Music. When I tried to enter dropbox folder (which is symlink), I've got the error text saying that d:\User\Dropbox refer to unreachable distanation. Can somebody explain what I've done wrong or point me to the solution?

Thanks to everyone!

p.s. due to lack of reputation points I'm unable to upload screenshot (anyway, it's in russian ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mklink /d <link-name> </target>` or use `/j` for junctions.

D is for directory symlinks as opposed to file symlinks.